# Game Center invitation programmatically with GKInvite list

Tags: ios6, game-center, gamekit, invitation

I am using Game Center in my game for iPhone in IOS 6. I have a tableview with a list of GameCenter´s friends. When I click a friend name, this friend recieve anotificatión (Game Center Notification) in her phone asking if he want to play the game against me. I am using my custom view all the time.
I am wondering how the other user can accept or reject the invitation to play the game. Can I have a uialertview telling YES or NOT, and if the user say yes create a new game with this two player using the following code?

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;
request.playersToInvite = [NSArray arrayWithObject:playerC_id];
[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] addPlayersToMatch:myMatch matchRequest:request completionHandler:nil];
```

I don´t know if this is possible. I would prefer another solution, having a list of all the GKInvite that a user received for their friends. And with this list the user should be able to accept or delete invitation. If the user accept the invitation the game will start.

How other apps manage game center invitation to play? How they accept or reject?When does the game start, when the player send an invitation to play or when the other player accept invitation? When is consider that a GKInvite is accepted?How can I get the list of GKInvite that I have?

Any solution to this issue? How to manage Game Center invitations?

Comment: Game center invitations are not working this days, I dont know what´s going on with game center SandBox server. I hope that your issue it is coming becuase of that.

Comment: I take it you want an alert view whether or not the user has selected the "alert" option in the game center notification settings?

Comment: No, you did not understand anything